# What are the command line tools of SourceTree 2.2?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

According to the Release Notes of SourceTree 2.2 command line tools can be installed automatically. This does not work on my Mac. What am I missing? The git commands are installed. P4Merge for nice diffing and merging is also installed.

Answer (score 0):

You install the command line tools from the SourceTree menu.

[image]